# Wrong return when validating regex with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Would someone take a look at my regex please? I'm trying to validate a `regex` group but it is matching too greedily.

```js
/*Should match only 16 characters in total & must begin with BE and follow by 14 digits */ 
 
var re = /(?<iban>[/BE\B/(?={0-9})])/gm
     
let correctIban  = 'BE71096123456769'              // => should match
let badIbanOne   = 'BE13466123456767590kd'         // => should NOT match
let badIbanTwo   = 'BE13466123456767590679080176'  // => should NOT match
let badIbanThree = 'AZ71096123456769'              // => should NOT match

console.log(re.test(correctIban));   // => true
console.log(re.test(badIbanOne));    // => false
console.log(re.test(badIbanTwo));    // => false
console.log(re.test(badIbanThree));  // => false
```

### Edit

Thanks for the help folks. Here is the code with capturing group syntax in `ES2018` for those who want to know: `(?<iban>^BE\d{14}$)`

Comment: Try `var re = /^BE[0-9]{14}$/`

Comment: why is <iban> in your reg exp??

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew's regex will do what you want - why do you have all this extra stuff in your regex, like `<iban>`? If this is relevant to the problem you're trying to solve, please explain.

Comment: That's a *named capture group*, something JavaScript does not support.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any particular reason for using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` (compatibility issues?) or just a personal taste?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel In JS, no matter what to use. Here, copy/paste.

Comment: @Pointy JS ECMAScrpt 2018 [supports named groups](http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html#named-capture-groups).

Comment: wow that's good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /^BE\d{14}$/;
```

Explanation:

- `^` - marks start of expression
- `BE` - literal characters'BE'
- `\d` - any digit (same as [0-9])
- `{14}` - quantifier - exact 14
- `$` - marks end of expression

All extra stuff was not needed.

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/4wF3NG/1

Comment: Your answer would be much more helpful if it included an explanation of what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: thanks for the answers @Anderson Pimentel, and the all you folks. I added the `<iban>` because it's a a new thing in javascript on `ES2018` perhaps, not needed but was giving it a try. Thanks for the explanation @all.